# ¿Como reiniciar el auto_increment de MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un pequeño trabajo con PHP, y necesito ayuda a la hora de eliminar un registro de una tabla. Inserto datos, y luego los elimino, pero el auto_increment continua en la ultima posición insertada. Quiero que al eliminar un dato, el auto_increment  también lo "haga" y  se reinicie al valor anterior.
¿Es posible?¿simplemente lo ignoro?
Agradezco enormemente cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Mi consejo es que no hagas ese tipo ce practicas.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ve a la pestaña de "Operaciones" en phpmyadmin y cuando abra busca el campo "auto increment". Pon "1" y listo. Eso por cada tabla dentro de tu base de datos.

Para editarlo desde el código, solo haz esto:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE tu_tabla_va_aqui AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
```

Nota: El valor de "1" no es obligatorio. Puedes hacer esto para obtener el valor del autoincrement:

```
$ultimo_id;

$query = "SELECT * FROM tu_tabla_va_aqui ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";

$resp = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Error");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resp)){
    $ultimo_id = $row["id"];
}
```

Y una vez que obtienes el último ID (esto antes de eliminar el ultimo elemento, tal y como encionaste en tu pregunta), le restas "1", y ese valor es el que va en:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE tu_tabla_va_aqui AUTO_INCREMENT = '$ultimo_id'";
```

Espero que te sirva mi respuesta. Saludos!

P.D: Dependiendo de cómo te manejes en tu código, es recomendable que utilices esta práctica. Ya que si en algún momento precisas mostrar todos los registros que tienes en tu tabla, no decrementas el id del auto-increment, y no haces la aclaración **if(mysqli_num_rows($respuesta)>0){//enviar/mostrar datos}**, van a ocurrir errores devido a los "id" que no existan tras haber sido eliminados en el pasado. Por eso, ya sea que hagas esta verificación extra que acabo de mencionar o alteres el auto_increment de la tabla, ambas podrían considerarse como soluciones prácticas y correctamente utilizadas. Suerte!