# Reiniciar numero de Factura en plantilla AdminLT

Tags: php, html, css3, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Descargue un sistema web para administrar las compras y ventas en problema es que las facturas empiezan en 1000 como ven en la foto de referencia, ¿como puedo hacer para reiniciar el numero de factura a 0? Gracias!

Comment: No, de que manera lo haria?

Comment: Eso es lo que necesito reiniciar los Id, para que empieze desde 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para reiniciar el auto incrementable ejecutas:

```
ALTER TABLE <nombre de tu tabla> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Lo más normal es empezar por 1 los ids de cualquier tabla, si de verdad necesitas que empiece desde 0 tienes que usar:

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

---

Trata de usar el buscador antes de formular tu pregunta, esto ya ha sido contestado:

[Como reiniciar el auto_increment de MYSQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/11331)

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono correctamente! Saludos!