# ¿Como cambiar AUTO_INCREMENT en una tabla en mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, autoincremento

Estoy tratando de inicializar una tabla en 1001, pero el auto_increment se queda en 1, aunque me dice que se ejecuto con exito.
ya intente

alter table your_table_name auto_increment = 1001

pero sin exito

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como reiniciar el auto\_increment de MYSQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11331/como-reiniciar-el-auto-increment-de-mysql)

Comment: Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8a3992d37f5a61d133d73632262f0b1), espero le sea útil.

Comment: Tienes activado el "AUTO_INCREMENT"? Recuerda que no debe tener valor por defecto ese campo. Mejor muestranos la estructura de tu tabla

Answer (score 0):

Intenta probar con esto

```
ALTER TABLE tutabla 
ALTER campo SET DEFAULT 1001;
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Lo que pusistes no serviria para cambiar el `AUTO_INCREMENT`, solo modificar el campo de una tabla

Comment: @JuanRivera es lo que el esta diciendo que modifique el valor del auto incremente que en vez de comenzar en 1 comience en 1001, lo que le digo es que el valor por defecto de ese campo no sea 1 , si no el que el mencion

Comment: El OP no quiere comenzar "siempre" con 1001, sino inicializar con ese valor como el dice "*Estoy tratando de inicializar una tabla en 1001*". Lo que haces es "setear" el valor por defecto en 1001, no inicializar